# node js with express image error

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I'm currently making a simple server and had a problem about adding image on the website. the image breaks when I add the image directory on the program code.
how can I solve this problem?

The code:

[image]

And this is what is shown on website, you can see that images are broken:

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question, nobody likes looking at small text in an image to try to see what's wrong.

Comment: Umm... what code? sorry iIm new here so I don't know well about this site. I was trying to upload an image, but it said that I could only upload the links of the images how did you uploaded the images?

Comment: Read the help section on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `sre` to `src`. If it is still not working, be sure that the path is correct. You can also take a look to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp).

Comment: It works now. Thank you so much! I should need to be more careful about such typing errors. once again thanks :)

Comment: done it. I may pass it if I did not see your reply cuz I'm new here. lol